# Haskell: Deriving Show for list of big tuples

Tags: haskell

Suppose that I have the following lists

```
[((Int, Int), [[Char]], [[Char]], Bool, Bool, Bool)]
[(Int, Int, [Char], [Char], [Char], [Char], [Char], [Char], [Char], [Char])]
```

I know that in order to be able to print them I need to define them as a new data type, then make an instance of Show but is there any way to avoid it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For tuples that big you should start using records, otherwise you *will* forget what's what.

Comment: yeah, i know, but since it is an assignment, it has some constraints

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's replace all the `[Char]` by `String` to get rid of some of the bracket overload:

```
[((Int, Int), [String], [String], Bool, Bool, Bool)]

[(Int, Int, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String)]
```

These can already be printed:

```
Prelude> let x = replicate 2 ((1,2), ["a", "b"], ["c", "d"], True, False, True) :: [((Int,Int), [String], [String], Bool, Bool, Bool)]

Prelude> :type x   -- displays the type of x
x :: [((Int, Int), [String], [String], Bool, Bool, Bool)]

Prelude> print x
[((1,2),["a","b"],["c","d"],True,False,True),((1,2),["a","b"],["c","d"],True,False,True)]
```

and

```
Prelude> let x = replicate 2 (1,2,"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h") :: [(Int,Int,String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String)]

Prelude> :type x
x :: [(Int,
       Int,
       String,
       String,
       String,
       String,
       String,
       String,
       String,
       String)]

Prelude> print x
[(1,2,"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"),(1,2,"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h")]
```

Comment: @KudayarPirimbaev What interpreter are you using? GHCI or Hugs? If you're using Hugs, you should switch to GHCI as soon as possible.

Comment: @KudayarPirimbaev Which `let x = ...` statement? There are two. Although they both work fine when I paste them into GHCI.

Comment: hugs, yeah, it works on ghci, but I can't use it in my assignment :( i'll try to debug my program with ghci anyway, thanks

Comment: One of the problems with Hugs is that it only includes `Show` instances for tuples up to size 7, and one of your examples uses a tuple of size 10. If you are stuck using Hugs, you'll have to write the `Show` instance yourself (but you should tell your instructor to update to GHCI - Hugs has been out of date for more than 5 years now).

Comment: @ChrisTaylor Hugs is a better teaching platform because it's faster to compile and gives much better error messages. That'll be why his instructor is using Hugs. Writing Show instances is a good exercise for a beginner; I think this is deliberately necessary.

Comment: @AndrewC Hmm, good points. I hadn't considered pedagogical value. Still, I think there's value in getting used to the 'real world' platform as soon as possible (I learned using GHCI, as did most Haskell developers - I'm not sure why we think people who are starting out now need additional help).